# cpp/cli interop dll breaks in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++-cli

I've been assigned the task of upgrading an old interop dll into visualstudio2015 with the  v140 toolset.

I'm getting an odd access violation now.

> Exception thrown at 0x000007fef7d3d95c (mscoreei.dll) in HostApp.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff

### Did anything change in cpp/cli from v110 to v140?

I can tell the error occurs when the **methods are defined in a separate cpp instead of inline in the `Foo.h`**. This work-around isn't possible since this is where I need to call managed objects.

Here is my attempt at reconstructing the outline of the code:

shared header IFoo.h

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
#define __API__ __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define __API__ __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class IFoo
{
  public:
    __API__ static IFoo* Create();

    virtual void DoSomething()=0;
 };
```

Foo.h

```
#include IFoo.h
class Foo : public IFoo
{
  public:
    Foo() { } // if inline no crash

    void DoSomething();
 };
```

Foo.cpp

```
 #include ManagedStuff.h
 #include Foo.h

 // Foo::Foo() { } // AV if not inline.

 void Foo::DoSomething()
 {
      gcroot<ManagedClass^> stuff = gcnew ManagedClass();
      .....
 }
```

FooImpl.cpp

```
 #include Foo.h
 IFoo* IFoo::Create()
 {
     IFoo* f = new Foo(); // CRASH if ctor is NOT inline.
     f->DoSomething(); //CRASH
     return f;
 }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? I remember something about the C++ compiler doesn't work well if you are  targeting a version of .NET older than the compiler itself (4.6 in this case), but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: .net version is unchanged 4.0

Comment: You could try changing it to 4.6 and see if that works. Unfortunately there isn't any UI to do this - you need to edit the project file manually. There should be a `TargetFrameworkVersion` tag - change its value to `v4.6`.

Comment: I'd like to keep it 4.0 since this isn't the only cppcli and c# project in the solution.

Comment: If you comment out the managed parts of Foo, does that work?

Comment: No. It doesn't work. And 4.6 doesn't help either.

Comment: Have a look at the  `ManagedStuff.h` Might be there is an unclosed `#pragma managed` inside. In that case the `Foo.cpp` code is treated as managed code. Inline `Foo::Foo()` escapes it.

Comment: I still haven't isolated the exact cause. But it has to do with exceptions being thrown across boundaries.